# How to divide a time-slot in quarter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to get time quarters based on two times
For example I have two time string

```
startTime = 5445458588989  //let suppose 5:10 AM
endTime = 585556513555     //let suppose 8:40 AM
```

The possible could be a method for example

```
//typescript
public getTimeslots(start: number, end: number) number[] {
  //Code goes here
}
```

So I want to get all quarters between these two times.
This can be possibly an array of time string

```
[
 445452115,    //5:15 AM
 985455514,    //5:30 AM
 542215558,    //5:45 AM
 321566899,    //6:00 AM
 987585159,    //6:15 AM
 ...
 982148552,    //8:30 AM
]
```

> PS: Strings here may not be valid, just for demonstration

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const start = new Date(startTime);
const end = new Date(endTime);

// Set start date to be the closest 15 minute interval
let closestInterval = Math.ceil(start.getMinutes()/15) * 15;
start.setMinutes(closestInterval);

// Array to store the intervals
const intervals = [];

// Create a loop to go through all 15 minute intervals.
while(start < end) { 
    // Push a copy of the current date to the list
    intervals.push(Object.assign({}, start));

    // Increment by 15 minutes.
    start.setMinutes(start.getMinutes() + 15);
}
```

After this you should have an array of Date objects within 15 minute intervals between your start and end time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have showed what you tried, but I found it fun. Can you try this?

```
getTimeslots(start: number, end: number) number[] {
  startMins = (new Date(start)).getMinutes();
  endMins = (new Date(end)).getMinutes();

  startGapToQuarter = (startMins % 15) * 60000;

  const quarters = [];
  for (let i = start + startGapToQuarter; i < endMins; i += 900000) {
    // to return dates change for this:
    // quarters.push(new Date(i));
    quarters.push(i);
  }

  return quarters;
}
```

Comment: `startGapToQuarter = startMins % 15;` This is a number between 0-14, not the closest 15 min interval. Check my answer below, you'll have to divide, round and multiply.

Comment: I know.... it is the gap.. if u add it to start, you get the first quarter after it.. right?

Comment: Ahh I see what you did, very clever

Comment: Thanks... but you were right, I had to turn it back to milliseconds... so I multiplied by 900000